# pyqt5 | how to make text display in QPlainTextEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want two numbers to be entered and one divided by the other and at the end the quotient is output to QPlainTextEdit, but I can' t do it right.
here is a problematic piece of code

```
def electrovolnyshablon():
    global ElectroVolSh
    ElectroVolSh = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    uie = ElectroVolni()
    uie.ShablonElectro(ElectroVolSh)
    ElectroVolSh.show()
    MainElectric.hide()
    uie.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText('Указывайте в метрах (м)')
    uie.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Указывайте в м/c")

    def nazadlzadacham():
        MainElectric.show()
        ElectroVolSh.hide()

    #############specifically here########################
    def obrabotka(): 
        dlinavolni = int(uie.lineEdit_2.text())
        skorc = int(uie.lineEdit.text())
        otvett = dlinavolni / skorc
        #if not skorc:
        #    otvett = dlinavolni / 300000000
        #else:
        #    skorc1 = int(skorc)
        #    otvett = dlinavolni / skorc1

        uie.plainTextEdit.setText(str(otvett))

    uie.pushButton.clicked.connect(obrabotka)
    uie.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(nazadlzadacham)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is the problem and what do you mean by "problematic"? Does it show a wrong value? Does it show something else? Does the program crash? Try to make yourself more clear, and also provide a [mre].

Comment: Code for setText looks fine to me. Is that code actually being executed? You can add print statements inside your obrabotka() method to help debug.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the text should be output via setPlainText, that is, it should look like this: `uie.plainTextEdit.setPlainText(str(otvett))`

Secondly, you need to convert to int after checking for an empty input.